# Possible to have 2 contextual filters with "or" rather than "and"?

Tags: 7, views

I would like to create a view that shows all nodes created by the currently logged in user OR where the currently logged in user has commented on.

D6 had a [views_or](http://drupal.org/project/views_or) module but it's not ported to 7.

Are there any simple solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OR is built in Views 3 (see this [issue](http://drupal.org/node/291660)) with a rather pleasant interface.

But for what you need, you can do this with a single filter: "Content: User posted or commented - *Display nodes only if a user posted the node or commented on the node.*"

[image: Content: User posted or commented - Display nodes only if a user posted the node or commented on the node.]

Views 3 AND/OR filter interface:
[image: Views 3 AND/OR filter interface]

Comment: thanks. I was referring to the "contextual filters". If I use the "filter criteria" for "Content: User posted or commented" I have to manually specify a user. I want to filter by the "currently logged in user". When I use that field for a "contextual filter" and specify "currently logged in user" it shows all content. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I just checked back in the contextual filters and this filter (Content: User posted or commented) exists there too.

Comment: yes, it does, but it doesn't work. The bug is tracked on http://drupal.org/node/972934 and a patch is available

Comment: patch worked and the view is now working with a contextual filter (Content: User posted or commented). Thanks again for the answer!!!